# Open Sign Modal when an unauthorized user accessing private route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using the PrivateRoute method to redirect the unauthorized user to the sign-in page. Here is the code for that file.

I do not want to use Dan Abramov's redux method to handle Modal.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      isAuthenticated
        ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
        : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/sign-in', state: { from: props.location} }} />)
      )}
  />
);
```

here is the route mentioned for that

```
<Route path="/incidents" component={IncidentPage}/>
<Route path="/security-advisories" component={IncidentPage}/>
<Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn}/>
<PrivateRoute path="/subscribe" component={Subscribe} isAuthenticated={this.props.isLoggedIn} />
```

But the requirement is to open the sign in modal when the unauthorized user hit the Private route.

Answer (score 0):

first create history

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory()
history.pushWithPrev = pathName => {
    history.push({
        pathname: pathName,
        state: { 
            from: history.location
        }
    })
}
export default history;
```

this function push to a url with saving previous location

second in your routing file import history and use it like below

```
import history from './history'
let switchLocation = history.location
    if(isAuthenticated) 
    {
        switchLocation = null
    } 
    else if(
            history.location && 
            history.location.state && 
            history.location.state.from
        ) {
        switchLocation = history.location.state.from
    }

<Router history={history}>
        <div>
             <Switch location={switchLocation}>
                   <Route path="/incidents" component={IncidentPage}/>
                   <Route path="/security-advisories" component={IncidentPage}/>
                   <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn}/>
             </Switch>
             <PrivateRoute path="/subscribe" component={Subscribe} isAuthenticated={this.props.isLoggedIn} />
        </div>
</Router>
```

and whenever you need to save your previous history use pushWithPrev function of history

for example use `history.pushWithPrev('/subscribe')`